# Изменение размеров элементов ActiveX Controls на листе Excel

Tags: excel, activex, controls

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

1. на лист excel добавляю ActiveX Controls - ListBox. У меня отображается на нужном месте и нужного размера;
2. скидываю книгу на другой компьютер с другим разрешение экрана;
3. открываю книгу и вижу, что элементы съехали кто куда;
4. смотрю опять у себя - все хорошо.

Понимаю, что проблема с разрешением экрана. Копал по разным сайтам и русскоязычным и англоязычным контентом, все проблему признают, но толкового решения не встретил.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил проблему установкой в коде размера и расположения каждого элемента на листе.